# Make links clickable except when they already are using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I found some examples that use regular expressions to detect patterns for URLs inside text paragraphs and add the HTML code to make them links. The problem I have with this approach is that, sometimes, the input paragraph contains both URLs written in plain text (which I want to convert to clickable) but also some URLs that already have markup for links. For example, consider this paragraph:

```
My favourite search engine is http://www.google.com but 
sometimes I also use <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">http://www.yahoo.com</a>
```

I only want to convert the Google link but leave the two Yahoo links as they are.

What I am after is a C# function that uses regex to detect URLs and convert them but which ignores URLs that either have "A" markup tags surrounding them or inside an "A" tag already.

**Edit**

Here is what I have so far:

```
PostBody = "My favourite search engine is http://www.google.com but sometimes I also use <a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">http://www.yahoo.com</a>";
String pattern = @"http(s)?://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);
System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(PostBody);
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
  PostBody = PostBody.Replace(matches[i].Value, String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", matches[i].Value, matches[i].Value));
}
ltrlPostBody.Text = PostBody;
```

And here is what I am getting (I split it in multiple lines for clarity):

```
My favourite search engine is 
<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> 
but sometimes I also use 
<a href="<a href="<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">http://www.yahoo.com</a>">
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">http://www.yahoo.com</a></a>">
```

I only want to convert the first link (in this case) because it does not already make part of a link markup.

Comment: We will gladly help you with this problem.  But, you must first _show us what you have done thus far_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net), which gives you more power (for example you don't want to escape

```
<script></script>
```

elements and style elements:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace ConsoleApplication3 {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var text = @"My favourite search engine is http://www.google.com but 
sometimes I also use <a href=""http://www.yahoo.com"">http://www.yahoo.com</a>
<div>http://catchme.com</div>
<script>
  var thisCanHurt = 'http://noescape.com';
</script>";
      var doc = new HtmlDocument();
      doc.LoadHtml(text);
      var regex = new Regex(@"http(s)?://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
      var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()");
      foreach (var node in nodes) {
        if (node.ParentNode != null && (node.ParentNode.Name == "a" || node.ParentNode.Name == "script" || node.ParentNode.Name == "style")) {
          continue;
        }
        node.InnerHtml = regex.Replace(node.InnerText, (match) => {
          return string.Format(@"<a href=""{0}"">{0}</a>", match.Value);
        });
      }

      var builder = new StringBuilder(100);
      using (var writer = new StringWriter(builder)) {
        doc.Save(writer);
      }
      var compose = builder.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Regex already written to determine when text is wrapped with an anchor tag, you can use RegularExpressions to determine if your input is a match, via http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx

Can do something as simple as

```
private string Pattern = "whateverregexpatternyouhavewritten";
private bool MatchesPattern(string input)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(Pattern, input);
}
```